# How to delete a specific line from a file in unix?

Tags: unix, sed

I have a very large file from which I need to delete a specific line (line number 941573 )

I'm somewhat new to this environment, but I've been googling the problem to no avail.

I've tried using the sed command as such, but it doesn't seem to be working

```
sed -e '941572,941574d' filenameX > newfilenameY
```

I've also tried

```
sed -e '941573d' filenameX > newfilenameY
```

Yet the 'newfilenameY' file and the original file 'filenameX' both still contain the line that I'm trying to delete. It's a fastq file, though I don't see how that would make any difference. Like I said I'm new to unix so maybe I've gotten the sed command wrong

Comment: I've just tried this approach (with a much smaller file) and it all appears to work. Perhaps you want to recheck ?

Comment: I would suggest you run `sed -ne '941573p' filenameX` to see if sed is counting the line numbers the way you expect it to.

Answer (score 10):

[`d`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Common-Commands.html#Common-Commands) deletes a line/lines. So your second approach works.

```
$ sed '941573d' input > output
```

**Long Example:**

```
% for i in $(seq 1000000)
do
echo i >> input
done
% wc -l input
1000000 input
% sed '941573d' input > output
% wc -l output
999999 output
% diff -u input output                                      :(
--- input       2012-10-22 13:22:41.404395295 +0200
+++ output      2012-10-22 13:22:43.400395358 +0200
@@ -941570,7 +941570,6 @@
 941570
 941571
 941572
-941573
 941574
 941575
 941576
```

**Short Example:**

```
% cat input
foo
bar
baz
qux
% sed '3d' input > output
% cat output             
foo
bar
qux
```

Comment: How is this different from what the OP is doing, aside from the -e, which (I think) should make no difference ?

Comment: @BrianAgnew There is no difference. The second approach of the OP works.

Comment: The second approach doesn't work guys, I've been trying it all morning :/

Comment: Then your question is incomplete. As you can see from both my examples, `d` works. What information is missing from your question?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to remove one or more lines from a file.

*Syntax:*

```
sed '{[/]<n>|<string>|<regex>[/]}d' <fileName>      
sed '{[/]<adr1>[,<adr2>][/]d' <fileName>
/.../=delimiters
n = line number
string = string found in in line
regex = regular expression corresponding to the searched pattern
addr = address of a line (number or pattern )
d = delete
```

Answer (score 0):

I generated a test file with 1000000 lines and tried your `sed -e '941573d' filenameX > newfilenameY` and it worked fine on Linux.

Maybe we have some other misunderstanding.  Line numbers count from one, not zero.  If you counted from zero then you would find line 941572 was missing.

Did you try a `diff filenameX newfilenameY`?  That would highlight any unexpected changes.

I don't know much about FASTQ format, but are you sure we are talking about text file line numbers, and not sequence numbers?

There is a general line length limit of 4096 bytes, do any of your lines exceed that? (That's unlikely, but I thought it worth the question).